# interpolation in Angular 2 not working

Tags: angular, templates, interpolation

I'm using `Plot.ly` in Angular 2 to create a heatmap plot.  I want the "view extents" (the endpoints of the x-axis in the plot) to show up in the DOM via interpolation whenever I change the axis' visible range in the layout of the plot via zooming.  The interpolation refuses to update despite attempting to force change detection via `ChangeDetectorRef` and `NgZone`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
    <div class="card-content white-text">
      <span class="card-title">2D View</span>

      <!-- These aren't updating -->
      {{sliceIndexStart}} - {{sliceIndexEnd}}

      <div #plotly id="plotly" name="plotly" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
        <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my Component class looks like this:

```js
/* Imports and declarations */
...


@Component({
  selector: 'app-two-d-view',
  templateUrl: './two-d-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './two-d-view.component.scss' ],
  providers: [ H5servTestService ]
})
export class TwoDViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() layout: any;
  @Input() options: any;
  @Input() displayRawData: boolean;
  @ViewChild('plotly') private plotly: ElementRef;

  private sliceIndexStart: number;
  private sliceIndexEnd: number;

  constructor(private dataService: H5servTestService) {
    this.sliceIndexStart = 1000;
    this.sliceIndexEnd = 2000;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      res => {
        /* Get data and specify layout/options */
        ...

        Plotly.newPlot('plotly', this.data, this.layout, this.options);
        this.plotly.nativeElement.on('plotly_relayout', data => {
          if (data[ 'xaxis.range[0]' ] && data[ 'xaxis.range[1]' ]) {
            /* Why isn't this updating the view??? */
            this.sliceIndexStart = <number>data[ 'xaxis.range[0]' ];
            this.sliceIndexEnd = <number>data[ 'xaxis.range[1]' ];
          }
        });
      },
      err => {
        toast(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I'm handling the relayout event of the plotly plot and if I `toast` the variables out, they are indeed updating in the component.  But the interpolation in the view template is not updating...

### Question

Why doesn't updating a component's instance properties percolate up to the view where I'm using interpolation to display those values?

### My thoughts so far:

- I'm really getting hung up on the fact that where I'm updating the view model is in a handler for the subscription I'm making on the `nativeElement` of the `@ViewChild` (`this.plotly.nativeElement.on('plotly_relayout', ...)`).

  - I don't know much about it yet, but does this put me in a different zone than the default one my change detection is running on?
  - Am I actually making changes to the object I think I am?  If not, how can I make the changes to the right object that will trigger a change in the view template?

Even if you have to correct my wording, any and all feedback is welcome.

Comment: Also, intellisense in Webstorm and Visual Studio Code both suggest that the `this` in the `OnRelayout` method has `sliceIndexStart` and `sliceIndexEnd` instance properties available.  However, when I open Augury in Chrome Dev Tools, My `TwoDViewComponent` lists instance properties that never changes (they remain `1000` and `2000`, respectively, as they were initialized).

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of a child component for the interpolated portion of my template and using an injected NgZone to run the update to the parent component's properties in that zone did the trick.  Not sure how this differed from a previous approach other than using a child component.  But oh well.